# Im setting up a Conda environment with python and want to commit to github but dont want to commit all dependencies

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a project I am working on locally with a env folder from condas for my data science dependencies. How do i commit so that I dont commit all the dependencies only the ones necessary.
Ideally want to run a line of install to get all the packages.